# How to find the longest line in a polygon

Tags: geometry, optimization, polygons, computational-geometry

My problem is finding the longest line segment completely inside of an arbitrary polygon (so it's not necessarily convex). That line can start and end on any point located on the outline of the polygon (so I'm not only considering the vertices).

I have trouble to even find some kind of source for literature or something on this topic.

Can anyone help me with this or point me to some sources?

[image: An example domain]

Comment: If you don't considerer the vertices, there may not exist a maximum, just a supremum. Just think of a square: you can fund diameters as close to the length of the diagonal as you wish, but you can never attain that value.

Comment: @PierreCarre Hey thanks for your answer. Your answer makes sense. I'm not excluding the vertices however.

Comment: On [github](https://github.com/BradleyWood/Longest-Line-In-Polygon) someone published a java application which does what you want. Maybe his explanations are helpful for you.

Comment: It should be possible to argue that the longest segment passes through at least two vertices (not necessarily as endpoints) and consider all such pairs.

Comment: @pH74 Thanks I already found this but I didn't consider it to be optimal. Going to look into that again.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek Thanks. I guess that makes sense. I thought that this wouldn't work, but I can't come up with a counter example on the spot. Going to try to argue for your approach more rigorously.